# ubuntu os porting to android device Xiaomi redmi1s

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Yesterday I had tried to flash xiaomi redmi1s(cynogenmod mokee) for ubuntu touch.After configuration for ubuntu touch when i put the command "ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap" 
 **after that text comes device msm8266 isnot found on server**
device=is armani
I know I am new comer. I am having knowledge of C++ and doing practice on qt.
Now I want to develop the custom ubuntu touch rom for redmi1s.
as per my consideration i have to know the hardware configuration of phone(please tell me how to know), after that drivers(please tell me how to know) of each chipset and sensors(please tell me how to know) is that correct.Ubuntu software for hardware and configure it. is that correct?
if not then please give me the sequence so that i can follow for any phone.
please reply.

Thanks and regards,
Madhusudan Jadhav

Comment: As you have noticed, there are no compiled images for that device. So, you'll have to actually make a port. That involves quite a bit of tinkering with hardware drivers and kernel configuration. Here are [Porting Guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/) and [Kernel Source](https://github.com/armani-dev) of the device. Also someone has started porting and discussing on the forum: https://forums.ubports.com/topic/14/compiling-ubuntu-touch-for-xiaomi-redmi-1s